# Save Button Events on Alfresco Workflow Form

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, activiti

I have an Alfresco form on which I have drop down values. The same values are attached as aspect (properties) with document that is attached with this form. When I click on "**Save And Close**" button (which is the default of form)  the form successfully saves its states. However, the attached aspect does not update according to the changes. Also I have some custom buttons on this form which I have defined in my model, when I click on them the form and attached aspects with document successfully saved. Can anyone tell me how to save changes in aspect for "**Save and Close button**"?

For custom buttons I write below code in my **bpmn file**. In **complete** event of task it works perfectly for custom buttons, but for "**save and close**" button (default button) **complete** events do not trigger.

**Here is my code:**

```
bpm_package.children[0].properties["rtwf:documenttype"] = task.getVariable('rtwf_documenttype');
bpm_package.children[0].save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don t think there is a way of doing this:

- There is no event defined in activiti takslisteners that triggers when clicking save and close.
- A different approach I can think of, is to use an alfresco behaviour on update of a node that has the type of the given task type, but it appears that activiti task variables are not stored in a node but in the activiti DB table.